# Feet IK raycast hits an edge, and doesn't know what rotation to use

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm currently working on some feet IK and this is working correctly until the raycast hits an edge. At this moment the raycast uses both faces of the edge for a rotation reference, which causes the foot to jitter between the two positions.[Reference Gif](https://66.media.tumblr.com/f86635eaf560bb1baa69432301bb50b6/tumblr_inline_pr10rdTqzV1vn3qbe_500.gif)

I'm wondering how I could solve this, I have tried lerping between 2 positions and rotations i.e. (currentPos to targetPos), but due to the raycast always checking the surface it's not working. I'm looking for a solution, where I can say something like; Pick one of the two target positions or rotations.

I hope someone can advise me.

Comment: Off the top of my head the easiest solution I can think of would be to use 2 raycasts 1 for the heel and 1 for the toes and calculate which normal to use if they are different. which would give you the added bonus of max angle the foot could rotate within your logic.

Comment: Wouldn't this have a huge hit on performace? And with this scenario one of the two raycasts can still hit an edge and jitter the placement?

Comment: The performance shouldnt be an issue aslong as you keep the distance the raycasts are cast down the minimum you need which should be done as much as possible (is unlikey you need to check for the foot angle with a raycast much longer than the foot length), as for when the toes for example are on an edge using the middle ground from both normals should lessen the jitter a significant amount. Also maybe look into BoxCast for a cast thats the size of the foot. rather than a single point and use that to calculate which normal you wish to use..

Comment: @QuincyNorbert raycasts are cheaper than you think, as long as you manage your layers, you can't really feel them unless you do thousands per frame

Comment: @zambari Thanks for the info, I was always under the impression rayCasts we're very expensive performance wise.

Comment: @akaBase would a spherecast be a more appropriate solution? I have never worked with spehercasts, but lets say the sperecast  hits multiple normals can you get like the average rotation?

Comment: @QuincyNorbert yes, I was surpiresed myself untill I started benchmarking, the physics as in moving rigidbodies is way more expensive than just firing raycasts into space and seeing if there's something there - Physix is very optimised raycast wise, they are practically free compared to many other things

Comment: @QuincyNorbert From a quick test yes, SphereCast will fix your problem.

Comment: @akaBase I have never written a spherecast, but I'll give it a go! I'll keep you posted!

Comment: @QuincyNorbert https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html

Comment: Haven't tested it for long, but it seems to be working! Thanks alot @akaBase I can't answer my own question yet, would you mind typing Spehercast as the answer? I will gladly mark it as the correct answer! Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issues I had I used a Spherecast instead of a Raycast as @akaBase suggested. It seems the sphere calculates an avarage, which works perfectly fine.